# Spring Boot project don't work

Tags: spring-boot

I imported a spring boot project, but all classes are showing error even having no error in the code. I tried using the `mvn clean install` command to try to solve the problem, but I could not resolve it. Anyone have any idea why these errors?

Comment: Right click to download maven dependencies on project->got to maven->update project

Comment: Inside project directory: run a command on terminal:->  mvn dependency:tree then run mvn spring-boot: run

Comment: can you post error here @user

Answer (score 0):

try to remove the project from workspace and import it again, then run

```
- mvn clean install
- mvn dependency:resolve
- mvn eclipse:eclipse (if you are using eclipse)
```